# Simple kivy tab example

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am new to Android development using Kivy. I have created a tab structure like below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
  def build(self):
      tb_panel= TabbedPanel()

      # Create text tab          
      th_text_head = TabbedPanelHeader(text='Text tab')
      th_text_head.content= Label(text='This is my text content')

      # Create image tab
      th_img_head= TabbedPanelHeader(text='Image tab')
      th_img_head.content= Image(source='sample.jpg',pos=(400, 100), size=(400, 400))

      # Create button tab
      th_btn_head = TabbedPanelHeader(text='Button tab')
      th_btn_head.content= Button(text='This is my button',font_size=20)

      tb_panel.add_widget(th_text_head)
      tb_panel.add_widget(th_img_head)
      tb_panel.add_widget(th_btn_head)          

      return tb_panel

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

I want to add the login widget to the default tab. The code for login widget is:

```
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.0.5')

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty 

class loginView(Widget): 
    status=ObjectProperty(None) 
    def validate(self,username,password): 
        print "user - ", username
        print "pwd - ", password
        if username == password: 
            print "in if - ", username,password     
            self.status.text="Login sucess" 
        #mainClass().run() 
        else: 
            self.status.text="Login failed" 

class afterLogin(Widget): 
    def dumb(self): 
        l = BoxLayout(cols="2") 
        btn = Button(text="ad") 
        l.add_widget(btn) 
        print "flag" 

class mainClass(App): 
    def build(self): 
        return loginView()  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    mainClass().run()
```

and the kv file is :

```
#:kivy 1.0.5 

<loginView>: 
    status:result 
    Label: 
         text:"Contacts Manager" 
         pos:600,600 
         font_size:40 


    Label: 
         text:"Username" 
         pos:450,400 

    Label: 
         text:"Password" 
         pos:450,300 

    TextInput: 
         multiline:False 
         pos:600,425 
         size:200,45 
         font_size:20 
         id:username 

    TextInput: 
         multiline:False 
         pos:600,325 
         password:True 
         size:200,45 
         font_size:20 
         id:password 
    Button: 
         text:"Login" 
         size:100,50 
         pos:600,250 
         on_press:root.validate(username.text,password.text) 
    Label: 
         text:"" 
         pos:600,100 
         id:result 
<afterLogin>: 
    Label: 
         text:"Welcome"
```

How can I add this code into the default tab?

Comment: the LoginView code doesn't display anything. I think you forgot to post the .kv file.

Comment: edited the code and added kv

Comment: you just copy the same python file again with an extra line

Comment: sorry bymistake. updated the same

Comment: I posted a 2nd answer explaining how to include your loginView.

Comment: The Title of this case should be modified as 'Simple Kivy default tab example'

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following 2 properties: `default_tab_text` and `default_tab_content`.

So, assuming your login code is the following one (yours doesn't work):

```
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.0.5')

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Loginview>:
    cols:2
    padding: 200
    Label: 
        text: "username"
    TextInput:
    Label: 
        text: "password"
    TextInput:
""")

#Name of classes are always uppercase
class LoginView(GridLayout): 
    pass
```

Assuming that code is in the same folder as the main.py (the code that has the `TabbedPanelApp`). Then

1) Import the LoginView (I put it upper-case because it is a class)

```
from login import LoginView
```

2) Modify the `build` method of `TabbedPanelApp` as follows

```
class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        tb_panel= TabbedPanel()
        tb_panel.default_tab_text = "Login Tab"
        tb_panel.default_tab_content = LoginView()
```

You can also modify the whole `TabbedPanelHeader` with the `default_tab_cls` property, or even deactivate the default tab with the `do_default_tab` property. So, you have many options. Just take a look to the [doc](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name of the python file is `loginview.py` and it is in the same folder of the `main.py`, adding the following to your code should fix your problems (it works on my computer already):

```
from loginview import loginView

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
  def build(self):
      tb_panel= TabbedPanel()

      tb_panel.default_tab_text = "Login Tab"
      tb_panel.default_tab_content = loginView()
```

But notice that classes should be written in uppercase. This is not mandatory but it is a good practice. Names like `loginView` are meant for variables in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I studied the Kivy in a long time ago, maybe it was before the time of this case, but I also did not use it a long time because Kivy kept in the version 1.0 a very long time, recently I picked it up again and studied the tabbedpanel, basically I use Kivy with its separation of concerns principle, that is I keep the UI design in .kv file, for this case my solution is as follows,

in the .py file

```
class AnyName(TabbedPanel):
    class LoginView(Widget):
        pass
# below as your code
...
```

in the .kv file

```
AnyName:

<LoginView>:
# below as your code
    ...

<AnyName>:
    default_tab_text: 'LoginView'
    default_tab_content: root.LoginView()
    # below as your code
    ...
```

There is a more basic solution, but I have stuck in here a while. I tried to use

```
default_tab_content: LoginView()
```

in .kv file directly as other classes used for non-default tab, the class LoginView and other classes all defined in the main.py file. But for running the modification it always shows

```
NameError: name 'DefaultTab' is not defined.
```

Then I tried to import the class LoginView in .kv file as

```
#:import LoginView main
```

but it always shows

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here the Kivy import format seems to exist some difference from the standard Python import format. In Python if the class LoginView is stored in a module
loginview.py then we may use below code line to import the class LoginView,

```
from loginview import LoginView
```

and we may call the class constructor LoginView() directly in the Python code. But if we import the same class in .kv file with the corresponding KV code line,

```
#:import LoginView logiview
```

then when we need to call the class constructor LoginView(), it must indirectly call it as

```
LoginView.LoginView()
```

otherwise it will happen TypeError.

So we provide the more basic solution as below (here we store the classes AnyName and LoginView both in the module main.py)

in .py file

```
class AnyName(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class LoginView(Widget):
    pass
```

in .kv file

```
#:import LoginView main.LoginView
 ...
AnyName:
 ...
<LoginView>:
 # below as your code
 ...

<AnyName>:
    default_tab_text: 'LoginView'
    default_tab_content: LoginView()
```